# Sum of squares in linear contrast

Tags: anova, contrasts

$$SS(\text{Contrast}) = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i\bar{X}_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i^2/n_i}$$

This is a formula from Howell's Statistical Methods for Psychology. The author claims that one of the major advantages in using linear contrasts is that they can be easily converted into sums of squares. But he didn't explain how he arrived at the formula. Can anyone help me make sense of it?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CV. If we must infer the context, I would guess you are modeling data $X_{ij}$ as independent  random variables with $j$ ranging from $1$ to $n_i$ for each $i$ and means $\mu_i$ and a common variance $\sigma^2.$  Would that be correct?  If so, it might be of interest to note that the variance of $c_i\bar X_i$ is $c_i^2/n_i$ times $\sigma^2.$

Comment: @whuber Yes. That's what I'm working on. Sorry, I should've been more clear about the context. I'll make sure to fix that tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are studying one-way ANOVA. I would provide you an informal brief of the general framework underlying the formula you stated.

---

Let the general linear model be

$$\mathbf Y=\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta +\boldsymbol\varepsilon\tag 1\label 1$$

To test $\boldsymbol\Lambda^\top\boldsymbol\beta =\boldsymbol 0,$ one can see that the condition implies $\boldsymbol\beta\in\mathcal C(\boldsymbol \Lambda) ^\perp=:\mathcal C(\mathbf U)\implies \boldsymbol\beta=\mathbf U\boldsymbol\gamma;$ substituting this in $\eqref 1$ would reduce the model to $\mathbf Y=\mathbf X_0\boldsymbol\beta +\boldsymbol\varepsilon, ~~\mathcal C(\mathbf X_0) \subset \mathcal C(\mathbf X). $ To test our hypothesis, we would check how "large" is the squared projection of $\mathbf Y$ onto the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal C(\mathbf X_0) $ with respect to $\mathcal C(\mathbf X) $ i.e. $\mathcal C(\mathbf X_0) ^\perp_{\mathcal C(\mathbf X) }= \mathcal C(\mathbf M-\mathbf M_0)$ where $\bf M$ and $\mathbf M_0$ are the perpendicular projection operators onto $\mathcal C(\mathbf X) $ and $\mathcal C(\mathbf X_0) $ respectively. Specifically we would be working with $\mathbf Y^\top (\mathbf M-\mathbf M_0) \mathbf Y/r(\mathbf M-\mathbf M_0). $ We would be comparing it with $\mathrm{MSE}= \mathbf Y^\top (\mathbf I-\mathbf M) \mathbf Y/r(\mathbf I-\mathbf M)$ to evaluate how true rhe reduced model is.

If $\boldsymbol\Lambda^\top\boldsymbol\beta$ is estimable, then $\boldsymbol\Lambda^\top=\mathbf P^\top\mathbf X. $ So, the reduced model would be $\mathbb E[\mathbf Y] \in \mathcal C(\mathbf X) ~\wedge~\mathbb E[\mathbf Y] \perp \mathcal C(\mathbf{MP}) ~~(\textrm{as}~~\mathbf{P}^\top\mathbf X\boldsymbol \beta=\mathbf{P}^\top\mathbf{MX}\boldsymbol\beta=0)\implies \mathbb E[\mathbf Y]\in\mathcal C(\mathbf X) \cap \mathcal C(\mathbf{MP})^\perp\implies \mathcal C(\mathbf{X_0})^\perp_{\mathcal C(\mathbf X) }=\mathcal C(\mathbf{MP}).$ (Also $r(\boldsymbol\Lambda) =r(\mathbf M_{\mathbf{MP}}).$) Therefore, the quadratic form that we discussed above can be written as $$\mathbf Y^\top \mathbf M_{\mathbf{MP}}\mathbf Y=\mathbf Y^\top \mathbf{MP}\left(\mathbf P^\top \mathbf{ MP}\right)^-\mathbf P^\top\mathbf{MY}= \hat{\boldsymbol\beta}^\top\boldsymbol\Lambda\left[\boldsymbol\Lambda^\top(\mathbf X^\top X)^-\boldsymbol\Lambda\right]^-\boldsymbol\Lambda^\top\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}.$$ If we have single degree of freedom as our hypothesis, then it becomes simpler: $$\frac{\left(\boldsymbol\lambda^\top\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}\right)^2}{\left[\boldsymbol\lambda^\top(\mathbf X^\top X)^-\boldsymbol\lambda\right]}\tag 2\label 2.$$ This is the required *sum of squares* (numerator of the $F$ statistic) which we would be using to deduce the sum of squares of contrast aka OP's formula.

*To be continued...*

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Plane Answers to Complex Questions: The Theory of Linear Models, *Ronald Christensen,* Soringer Science$+$Business, $2011, $ sec. $3.2, 3.3,4.2.$